# how does facebook has different layouts when i browse from different devices?

Tags: iphone, facebook, ipad, templates, layout

i was wondering how does facebook shows different types of layouts on different devices? i see a standard template on Desktop browser, and different on mobile devices and iPhone, and iPads,

are these each layouts created and set somehow to appear according to which device it is accessed from or facebook automatically detects the device and shows the appropriate layout?

Comment: Facebook detects the browser you are using with User-Agent string.

Answer (score 0):

While using desktop you are browsing http://facebook.com/ and from mobile http://m.facebook.com/ Facebook is detecting device type and displaying content as per devices.

Using media query, you can display same page in different layout. Refer this http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries

Answer (score 0):

I believe Facebook uses wurfl for device detection - or so their site has claimed for a while  : http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/